# Notifying an instance as down using a ServiceCache in Curator

Tags: apache-curator

The documentation for Curator (http://curator.apache.org/curator-x-discovery/index.html) says:

`If a particular instance has an I/O error, etc. you should call ServiceProvider.noteError() passing in the instance.`

I am using a `ServiceCache` to get my instances, rather than a `ServiceProvider` (see [Using selection strategies with a cache in Curator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57009605/using-selection-strategies-with-a-cache-in-curator/57020383#57020383)).

Where can I find the `noteError()` method here? I can't find it on the cache object

Comment: It turns out I gave you misleading information and you may not need to directly use a service cache at all. See my other answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57059811/2048051

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `noteError()` on a ServiceCache, however as @Randgalt notes (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57059811/2048051) the best way is to not use a `ServiceCache` but rather just use `ServiceProvider`, because in the background that uses a cache anyway, and it has the `noteError()` method available.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CURATOR-531 has been raised to make the documentation clearer